# Плагин для MS Access 2016 при помощи VSTO C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, vsto

Необходимо создать плагин MS Access 2016 при помощи VSTO C#.

В шаблонах проектов студии есть разные типы проектов для Office

- Excel;
- Word;
- Outlook.

Но Access отсутствует.

Судя по скудной информации, которую я нахожу, можно использовать проект типа Excel, который потом как-то изменяется "вручную" под Access. Но полного руководства не нахожу.

Подскажите, как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать в Visual Studio
   Visio VSTO  Add-in
2. Заменить в файлах проекта:

   *ThisAddIn.cs*
   *ThisAddIn.Designer.cs*
   *ThisAddIn.Designer.xml*
   **.csproj*

"Visio" на "Access"

Пример - https://github.com/asheinkin/msaccess-vsto

---

Материалов немного, но они есть.
Посмотрите
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/archive/blogs/andreww/vsto-add-ins-for-access
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757203/develop-ms-access-2016-addin-ribbon-vsto-with-visual-studio-2015